# When deriving, when am I supposed to multiply with the derived argument?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

We learned deriving a while back in school and recently I took a test from mechanics and I got confused. We had to derive position to get the velocity. The equation looked something like this

$y=5*\sin(x)$

$y'=5*\cos(x)$**x'**

Now in math classes, if I was to derive the first equation, I would do it like this:

$y'=5*\cos(x)$

So it got me confused, when am I supposed to add that **x'**?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the reasons that the $y'$ notation is a bad one: it doesn't specify the quantity with respect to which you're deriving!

In your math class, you likely intended $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when you took the derivative.  In your mechanics class, however, you are likely differentiating with respect to time.  That is, we think of $x$ and $y$ as both being functions of $t$, and
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=5\cos(x(t))\frac{dx}{dt}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are taking the derivative with respect to.  If the prime indicates the derivative with respect to $x$, you have $x'=1$ and there is no need to use it.  If the derivative is with respect to something else, such as $t$ for time, you need it from the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

That x' is always present, it's just that when you operate with respect to x ,

$$\frac{d}{dx} x=1$$

so it is simplified. However, when you operate with respect to something else (like time "**t**"), you cannot simplify it, and thats why $$x'$$
shows up. This comes from the chain rule, $$\frac{df}{dg} =\frac{df}{dx}.\frac{dx}{dg}$$